# Considering all +ve int n>=0, such that 5*3^m + 4 = n^2 holds for some corresponding int m>=0. What is the sum of all such n?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Considering all +ve int n>=0, such that 5*3^m + 4 = n^2 holds for some corresponding int m>=0. What is the sum of all such n ? After trying many ways, I got two solutions of m,0 and 2. But I do not know how to prove it. And one thing, ***please*** do not take it as a **homework question**.

Comment: Hint:  $n^2-4=(n-2)(n+2)$

Comment: Would you Please explain in detail?

Comment: Unable to understand

Comment: I'll post something below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we had a solution $5\times 3^m+4=n^2$  We'd deduce that $n^2-4=5\times 3^m$ hence $$(n-2)(n+2)=5\times 3^m$$

Now, the gcd of $n-2$ and $n+2$ is a divisor of $4$ (as the two numbers differ by $4$).  In particular, that gcd is prime to both $3$ and $5$. Indeed, as $n$ is clearly odd we can deduce that $\gcd(n-2,n+2)=1$. Thus one of the two factors must be divisible by $3^m$ and the other  must be  $5$ or $1$.

Since we know that $n>2$ (as $n^2>4$ and $n>0$) we have $n+2≥5$.  If $n+2=5$ then $n=3$ and we get a solution (with $m=0$).  Otherwise $n+2>5$ so we must have $n-2=5$ or $n=7$.  That too gives a solution, with $m=2$  Thus, these are the only two solutions and the answer is $3+7=10$.